# Oracle database in Clojure

Tags: oracle, clojure

I 've been trying to get connection to Oracle database from Clojure but without success. My project.clj file:

```
(defproject db-examples "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
             [yesql "0.5.2"]
             [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.4.2"]
             [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1201-jdbc41"]]
:resources-paths ["resources/ojdbc6.jar"])
```

I added ojdbc.jar manually to resources folder I created in my project folder.

Here are details of my connection:

```
(def db {:classname "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     :subprotocol "oracle"
     :subname "//localhost:1521/my_database"
     :user "user"
     :password "password"})
```

and my function with query:

```
(defn get-all []
 (sql/query db ["select * from my_table"]))
```

When I call this function I get this error: Caused by java.sql.SQLException
   No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle://localhost:1521/my_database

```
        DriverManager.java:  689  java.sql.DriverManager/getConnection
        DriverManager.java:  208  java.sql.DriverManager/getConnection
                  jdbc.clj:  255  clojure.java.jdbc/get-connection
                  jdbc.clj:  176  clojure.java.jdbc/get-connection
                  jdbc.clj:  832  clojure.java.jdbc/db-query-with-resultset
                  jdbc.clj:  790  clojure.java.jdbc/db-query-with-resultset
                  jdbc.clj:  866  clojure.java.jdbc/query
                  jdbc.clj:  838  clojure.java.jdbc/query
               RestFn.java:  425  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
                  core.clj:   12  db-examples.core/get-all
                  core.clj:   11  db-examples.core/get-all
                  core.clj:   14  db-examples.core/eval4272
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect format of connection string - to have the proper JDBC connection string, your subname should be in format "thin:@server_ip:port:sid".

```
(def db {:classname "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     :subprotocol "oracle"
     :subname "thin:@localhost:1521:my_database"
     :user "user"
     :password "password"})
```

More info can be found here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/JDBC_Examples#Oracle

Comment: I still have the same java.sql.SQLException:
 No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:zaposleni

Comment: Ok, one last thing, try the second style of JDBC connection string;
:subname "thin:@localhost:1521/zaposleni" - if not, I am sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` must be in your classpath. A line like this in your Leiningen dependencies will add it: `[com.oracle/ojdbc6 "1.0"]`